# Each card does not open and close as expected when dynamically created with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```js
 "use strict";

const openModal = document.querySelector('[data-create]');
const exitModal = document.querySelector('[data-close]');
const saveBtn = document.querySelector('#save');

openModal.addEventListener('click', showModal);
exitModal.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
saveBtn.addEventListener('click', saveCard);

/*
  Detects if text has been inputed. If not, an error is shown
  if yes the createFlashCard and closed modal function are called.
*/
function saveCard() {
    let questionArea = document.querySelector('#question');
    let answerArea = document.querySelector('#answer');
    let showAlert = document.querySelector('.show-error-message');
    if (questionArea = null || questionArea.value == '') {
        if (answerArea = null || answerArea.value == '') {
            showAlert.classList.remove("hide-error");
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
            showAlert.classList.add("hide-error");
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        closeModal();
        createFlashCard();
    }
}


/*
  Removes the is-hidden css class to open modal
*/
function showModal(e) {
    let modal = document.querySelector('.modal-design');
    modal.classList.remove("is-hidden");
}

/*
    Adds the is-hidden css class to close modal
*/
function closeModal() {
    let modal = document.querySelector('.modal-design');
    modal.classList.add('is-hidden');
}

/*
    Creates a flash card using input string values.
    Then renders a card using the .innerHTML property.
    Each card rendered will be clickable to show the answer.
*/
function createFlashCard() {
    let questionText = document.querySelector('.question-text').value;
    let answerText = document.querySelector('.answer-text').value;
    let cardSection = document.querySelector('.card-container');
    let createArticle = document.createElement('article');
    createArticle.className += "card";
    createArticle.innerHTML = `
    <div class="card-question-button">
        <h4 id="title">${questionText}</h4>
        <button id="show">></button>
    </div>
    <div id="answer-card">
        <p id="answer-card-p">${answerText}</p>
    </div>`;
    cardSection.appendChild(createArticle);
    openCloseCards();
}

function openCloseCards() {
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.card-question-button');
    buttons.forEach(function (btn) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            let questions = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
            questions.classList.toggle("show-text");
        })
    })
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

/*
 variables
*/
:root {
    --primary-color:#5dcbd8;
    --secondary-color: hsl(186, 100%, 94%);
    --third-color:  #F6F6F8;
    --fourth-color: #fff;
    --button-border: none;
    --error-color: hsl(0deg 58% 70%);
    --shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0 hsla(0 , 0%, 0%, 0.2);
}

header {
    padding: 15px;
    color: var(--third-color);
    height: 100px;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

/**
Prompt question card
*/
.prompt-question {
    display: flex;
    padding: 15px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#create {
    border: var(--button-border);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    height: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    font-size: 25px;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

#create:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #b5f0f7;
}

/*
    Modal Design
*/
.modal-placement{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.modal-design {
    width: 600px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #F6F6F8;
    box-shadow:var(--shadow);
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.is-hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
}

.erase-modal-c {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

#erase {
    background-color:var(--error-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

#close {
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#erase:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

h3 {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

/**
    Textarea design 
*/
#question, #answer {
    height: 90px;
}

textarea {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 4px;
    resize: vertical;
}

#save {
    border: var(--button-border);
    margin-top: 25px;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color:var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--third-color);
}

#save:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #90d8e0;
}

.show-error-message {
    background-color: var(--error-color);
    color: var(--fourth-color);
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.hide-error {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

/* 
    Card container
*/
.card-container {
    display: grid;
    background-color: var(--third-color);
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#title {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color:var(--fourth-color);
    padding: 7px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow:var(--shadow);
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.card-question-button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.card-question-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*
 Answer card
*/
#answer-card {
    display: none;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

#answer-card-p {
    text-align: left;
}

.show-text #answer-card {
    display: block;
}

#show {
    border: none;
    background-color: var(--fourth-color);
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

#show:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    transform: translateX(-2px);
}

/* Media Queries */ 
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .prompt-question {
        box-shadow:var(--shadow);
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    .card-container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Flash Cards +</h1>
    </header>

    <article class="prompt-question">
        <button id="create" data-create>+</button>
        <p class="info">
            Create a new card
        </p>
    </article>

    <article class="modal-placement">
        <section class="modal-design is-hidden">
            <div class="erase-modal-c">
                <button id="erase" data-close>
                    <p id="close">+</p>
                </button>
            </div>
            <h3>Question</h3>
            <textarea class="question-text textA" id="question"></textarea>
            </div>
            <h3>Answer</h3>
            <textarea class="answer-text textA" id="answer"></textarea>
            <button id="save">Save</button>
            <div class="show-error-message hide-error">Please Submit Values</div>
        </section>
    </article>

    <section class="card-container">
    </section>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</html>
```

This is a flashcard project I am building. I am fairly new to programming and was looking for help on this particular bug that I cannot wrap my head around. Included in the gist is the css, html, and javascript code. Any tips on code structure is also appreciated.

Question:
When I dynamically create cards using JavaScript I want to show open and close behavior for each of them. The first card created does open and close as expected. However, the following cards do not. For example, one stays open while the other one closes.
I would like each card to open and close independently when clicked after dynamically being created. It seems the behavior is depending on the previous card.

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you call createFlashCard() The html that is generated:

```
<div class="card-question-button">
        <h4 id="title">${questionText}</h4>
        <button id="show">></button>
    </div>
    <div id="answer-card">
        <p id="answer-card-p">${answerText}</p>
    </div>
```

These elements will have the same ID's used more than once in a page when they should be unique. Add a unique identifier or remove the id attribute if its not needed. For example:

```
    let cardCount=0;
    
    function createFlashCard() {
        cardCount++;
        let questionText = document.querySelector('.question-text').value;
        let answerText = document.querySelector('.answer-text').value;
        let cardSection = document.querySelector('.card-container');
        let createArticle = document.createElement('article');
        createArticle.className += "card";
        let title="title"+ cardCount;
    let buttonID="show"+cardCount;
    ...
<button id=${buttonID}>
...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing your openCloseCards function, you are creating multiple event listeners based on the number of items in buttons.

I'd recommend adding the event listener in your createFlashCard function and removing the function definition of openCloseCards and it's call.

With this change the code seems to working as it should.

```
function createFlashCard() {
    let questionText = document.querySelector('.question-text').value;
    let answerText = document.querySelector('.answer-text').value;
    let cardSection = document.querySelector('.card-container');
    let createArticle = document.createElement('article');
    createArticle.className += "card";
    createArticle.innerHTML = `
    <div class="card-question-button">
        <h4 id="title">${questionText}</h4>
        <button id="show">></button>
    </div>
    <div id="answer-card">
        <p id="answer-card-p">${answerText}</p>
    </div>`;
    cardSection.appendChild(createArticle);
    createArticle.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        let questions = e.target.parentElement;
        questions.classList.toggle("show-text");
        console.log(questions.classList)
    })

}
```